# scenebuilder 8.5 custom jar not load, can't open fxml

Tags: scenebuilder

i download scenebuilder 8.5 java 8 version, before i used scenebuilder 8.4.1 without any problem.
With new one:
 - custom jar does not appear in list
 - open an fxml doesn't work (fxml created with scenebuilder 8.4.1 without any problem) even if i don't use my custom library
 - no log error appears, just no reaction on open project action button???

I try to install again the application but without success.
When i open scenebuilder in intellij, it works.

I have two questions:

- What should i check or do?
- How can i download scenebuilder 8.4.1

Answer (score 0):

i found why, it's a problem of my custom jar, i fix it and know it's ok